# Discrete math: If G is a regular graph. What is the degree of each vertex?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

**strong text**
Hi, I have a question about discreet math, and the motto goes like this:

For each $n \in N$ such as $n ≥ 3$, let's call $X_{n}:={1,2, ..., n}$. We define the simple graph $G_{n}$ as follows:

.) $V(G_{n})$ consists of all subsets $\{a, b\} ⊂ X_{n}$ such that $a$ different from $b$

.) the elements $\{a, b\}$ and $\{c, d\}$ are adjacent in G_n if and only if $\{a, b\}\cap \{c, d\}=∅$

The question is: Define $|V(G_{n})|$ and $|E(G_{n})|$ as a function of $n$.Hint: $G_{n}$ is a regular graph. What is the degree of each vertex?

My problem is about the hint, I don't know how to write the degree of vertex with conbinatory

Comment: You need try to format your questions using MathJax typsetting, and also explain what you've tried and where you are having trouble. This network is not meant to just be a place to get others to do homework problems. See: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Comment: The hint is a good one. Have you tried to answer that question?

Comment: Yes, I tried, but that's the problem. I don't know how to write the degree of the vertices with combinatorics

Answer (score 1):

The vertices are simply all the pairs $(a,b)$ where $a \neq b$. There are $n^2$ pairs $(a,b)$ where we allow $a=b$, and there are $n$ pairs of the form $(a,a)$. Thus, $\vert V(G_n)\vert = n^2-n = n(n-1)$. Now we examine $\vert E(G_n)\vert$. Fix a point $(a,b)$ and look at an arbitrary neighbor $(c,d)$. There are $(n-2)$ choices for $c$, since $c \neq a,b$ and $(n-3)$ choices for $d$ since $d \neq a,b,c$. Thus, there are $(n-2)(n-3)$ vertices adjacent to $(a,b)$. Now, we can use the Euler degree sum formula to compute $\vert E(G_n) \vert$, made very easy since $G_n$ is regular. The formula says
$$ \sum_v \mathrm{deg}_{G_n}(v) = 2 \vert E(G_n) \vert$$
Each vertex has the same degree, $(n-2)(n-3)$ and there are $n(n-1)$ such vertices. So, Euler's formula says $n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3) = 2 \vert E(G_n) \vert$. From here the answer can be easily read off.

Comment: I am confused by the way you write $V(G)$ since I thought it could be expressed as $n!/x!(n-x)!$ @physmath

Comment: You could write it as $\frac{n!}{(n-2)!}$ if you so wish but this does not really elucidate anything. In any case, the vertex set is just the set of all pairs that do not have repeated elements. If it helps, you could imagine an $n \times n$ grid representing the points in the graph. Then the points in $V(G)$ are all the points not on the diagonal, so $n^2 - n = n(n-1)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll think about it!

Comment: I have a doubt and that is that if we are talking about a simple graph, it means that it does not have loops, that is to say there are no vertices of the style (a, a)... we would have to consider them equal?

Answer (score 0):

Answer seems pretty straight forward with the hint given. Not sure what is your confusion, hope this clarifies.

Vertices are 2 element subsets of $X_n$. So, $|V(G_n)|=$ $n\choose2$.

Now, it remains to show that Graph is regular. Consider a vertex V={a,b} of G. This vertex is adjacent to all 2-element subsets of $X_n-\{a,b\},$i.e. degree of V is $n-2\choose2$, i.e. degree of any vertex in $G_n$.

So total number of edges $|E(G_n)|=0.5\times$$ n\choose2$$\times$$n-2\choose2.$ using degree sum formula.

Comment: Thank you! I understood the process.